# Making a Class Immutable

Tags: java, immutability

I am learning about immutable Objects. I have to make following class immutable. Did i do it right?

```
import java.awt.Point;
public class MyImmutablePoint {
    Point point;

    public MyImmutablePoint(Point point) {
        super();
        this.point = point;
    }

    public MyImmutablePoint() {
        this (new Point (0,0));
    }

    public Point getPoint() {
        return point;
    }

    public void setPoint(Point point) {
        this.point = point
    }
}
```

"Immutable" Class:

```
public final class MyImmutablePoint {
    private final Point point;

    public MyImmutablePoint(Point point) {
        this.point = point;
    }

    public MyImmutablePoint() {
        this (new Point (0,0));
    }

    public Point getPoint() {
        return point;
    }   
}
```

Iam not sure about the `toString` method though.
and maybe returning an object like Point can be modified as well like an array but not sure

Comment: **Format your code**. This is illegible.

Comment: The question to ask yourself is this: "*is it possible for me to change the internal state of my object after I've created it?*". If the answer is *yes*, then your object is not immutable. Remember that the internal state of your object is a product of the internal states of all of your member fields, so if *any* of your member fields are mutable your object needs to handle access to that field very carefully otherwise your object will be mutable.

Comment: @OP - if an answer solved your problem, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This signals to the rest of the community that the question has been solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## No

```
final Point p = new Point(0,0);
final ImmutablePoint ip = new ImmutablePoint(p);
```

Two examples:

```
//change the original Point passed in
p.x = 10
//use the getter and change the Point
ip.getPoint().x = 10
```

So, first you need to create a **defensive copy** of the `Point` taken in the constructor:

```
public MyImmutablePoint(Point point) {
    this.point = new Point(point);
}
```

Then you need to create a defensive copy of the `Point` returned from the getter:

```
public Point getPoint() {
    return new Point(point);
}
```

This all leads me to suggest that it would probably be better not to expose the internal `point` at all:

```
public final class MyImmutablePoint {

    private final Point point;

    public MyImmutablePoint(Point point) {
        this.point = new Point(point);
    }

    public MyImmutablePoint() {
        this.point = new Point (0,0);
    }

    public int getX() {
        return point.x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return point.y;
    }
}
```

Further **format your code** and **order your members**.

Comment: So should i give back a copy of Point?

oh i guess i cannot give a reference of a point but i shud give int x, int y
so that its either MyImmutablePoint() or MyImmutablePoint(x,y)

Comment: Ok thank you very much, i can see that now.
I guess the definition of an immutable object is that its thread safe as well.
So i rather synchronize my toString method

Comment: @TimoN. I don't understand your comment. Immutability and threadsafely are only tangentially related. My definition of an immutable object is that it's **immutable**. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) for more information.

Comment: i just remember my prof said that correct! constructed immutable Objects are also thread safe

Comment: @TimoN. Only under certain assumptions - an immutable object has to be seen to be immutable from the outside. An Immutable object could, for example, cache the results of expensive computations (for example your `toString` method) - this cache could be written in a non-threadsafe manner. So no, it is not always the case that an immutable object is threadsafe.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: in what way could your example with an internal cache not be thread safe that would still retain immutability? My understanding of internal caching means that it must always provide the same answer, regardless of how many threads are involved in the process of creating that answer. I'm thinking of something like `java.lang.String`'s hashCode, which does internal caching, can be calculated by multiple threads, but is guaranteed to provide the same result. In what way would a thread-unsafe cache still permit the object to be immutable?

Comment: @Grundlefleck ideally yes. And the above example is not immutable in the strict sense. But it would certainly be immutable in a _single_ threaded environment. Sadly I have seen my fair share of such bugs in classes documented as immutable.

Answer (score 5):

No it is not immutable. Point can still be modified by the creator of MyImmutablePoint. Ex:

```
    Point point = new Point(1, 1);
    MyImmutablePoint immutablePoint = new MyImmutablePoint(point);
    point.setLocation(0, 0);
```

Comment: So should i give back a copy of Point? oh i guess i cannot give a reference of a point but i shud give int x, int y so that its either MyImmutablePoint() or MyImmutablePoint(x,y)

Comment: I would use MyImmutablePoint(int x, int y) as constructor and I think I would instantiate a new Point based on those when returning. It is not good practice to have much more than a return row in a get-method, but in order to avoid mutability I would probably do so. I would not make a copy.